# License management software (Open Source)

Tags: open-source, database

I’m trying to find a solution for keeping our license information in our database.

Let’s say a customer bought something 5 years ago, so I will create a new cutomer and assign him the license he bought. In 5 years he purchases a new license and an upgrade for his old license. So I will create a new entry for the old license and a new license for the new product.

When I click on customer, software opens me a view with all actual and old licenses he owns.

Before licenses expire, I need to get an email alert.

Is there anything? Maybe a part of bigger package?

Comment: Do you look for a system that integrates with your existing database, or can it be an independent/stand-alone solution? -- Should it be a web-app for installation in your own server, or a local tool?

Comment: @Alex - did you manage to find anything?

Comment: How about a webshop like https://drupalcommerce.org/? You don't even have to expose it to the customer if you don't want, you can use it yourself.

Comment: looking for the same thing

Comment: Have you considered using a custom form / database maker app? Something like FileMaker, Tap Forms or Riley Form Maker? I had a similar task last year and ended up building my own form, so much easier...